# SUM and GROUP BY not echoing out correctly in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query where I get the expected results when I run it in phpMyAdmin but not when I echo it out in a php table

MySQL statement:

```
SELECT month, sum(amount) FROM sql_chart  GROUP BY month
```

table php:

```
<td><?php echo $chart_row->month ?></td>
<td><?php echo $chart_row->amount ?></td>
```

Code works fine if I remove sum (but obviously doesn't sum results). When I add sum back in nothing is displayed in the amount column

Comment: You need to give the result of the sum a name to easily be able to pick it up in the code, a'la `SELECT month, sum(amount) AS amount FROM sql_chart  GROUP BY month`